# Parameters for ROS Gazebo block laser plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

Can somebody tell me the parameters for ROS Gazebo block laser plugin?
I am using ROS-Groovy with gazebo 1.7.1 standalone.

Seems the following syntax is no longer valid

```
      <displayRays>false</displayRays>          
      <minAngle>-15</minAngle>
      <maxAngle> 15</maxAngle>
      
      <minRange>0.05</minRange>
      <maxRange>100.0</maxRange>
      <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>

      <verticalRayCount>30</verticalRayCount>
      <verticalRangeCount>30</verticalRangeCount>
      <verticalMinAngle>-20</verticalMinAngle>
      <verticalMaxAngle>  0</verticalMaxAngle>
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2741/parameters-for-ros-gazebo-block-laser-plugin/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A test .world can be found at `/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/test/test_worlds/gazebo_ros_block_laser.world`

```
            <sensor name="sensor_ray" type="ray">
                <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
                <ray>
                    <scan display="true">
                        <horizontal>
                            <samples>300</samples>
                            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
                            <min_angle>-0.5236</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>0.5236</max_angle>
                        </horizontal>
                        <vertical>
                            <samples>100</samples>
                            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
                            <min_angle>-0.5236</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>0.5236</max_angle>
                        </vertical>
                    </scan>
                    <range>
                        <min>0.05</min>
                        <max>50.0</max>
                    </range>
                </ray>
                <!-- test plugin -->
                <plugin name="plugin_1" filename="libgazebo_ros_block_laser.so">
                    <gaussianNoise>0.00</gaussianNoise>
                    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                    <updateRate>20</updateRate>
                    <topicName>test_block_laser</topicName>
                    <frameName>base_link</frameName>
                </plugin>
                <always_on>true</always_on>
                <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>
            </sensor>
```

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-10**:
Can you look at the [multisense_sl urdf file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/ae950c054dcf3e118d891dd61dbb4ffb82ca5404/ros/multisense_sl_description/urdf/multisense_sl.urdf?at=default) for an example?

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-07-03**:
please help!, is this working ? I am having the same problem!

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-07-10**:
this doesn't work properly man,